# jQuery and AJAX : Fill a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, autocomplete

Now, I want make a AJAX function in order to fill a form, after a selection in a menu.
So this is, my jQuery code :

```
('select').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url  : 'formulaire.php',
        data : formulaire,
        success: function(server_response){

        }
    });
```

And my PHP page :

```
include '../Modele/sql.php';

if (isset($_GET['formulaire'])){
$formulaire = $_GET['formulaire'];
$formulaire = array('formulaire' => $formulaire);

// On effectue la requête vers la base de données
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM saisie_formulaire WHERE FOR_ID = :formulaire';
$requete = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$requete->execute($formulaire);

$compteur = $requete->rowCount($sql);

// S'il y a un résultat, on retourne le nombre de lits pour chaque type et chaque période
if ($compteur >= 1){
    while ($resultat = $requete->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){


    }
}
```

But I don't have idea about how to return after my SQL Query for fill my HTML form.
Anyone has one ?

Comment: You mean, you get results from MySQL, but then you don't know what to do with these? Funny code mélange between français and anglais, en tous cas

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to use them for fill my form. Humm, my code is in French, not in English ^^

Comment: Uh well that's basic MySQL parsing : `$value = $resultat['columnName']`, for instance :  `$email = $resultat['email']`

Comment: Yes but how to fill the form with this value ? 
AN only <?php echo $value; ?> is enough ?

Comment: Oh no. The best to do is to encode the results as a json, then echo json_results. You will get this JSON client-side in the server_response variable. I'll write you an example, give me a minute.

Comment: Okay, I posted my example as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do :

```
$resultat = $requete->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat)) { // Transforming MySQL results into a regular array of data
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows); // Echo this JSON back to the client
```

And client-side, get this JSON data back :

```
('select').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url  : 'formulaire.php',
        data : formulaire,
        success: function(json){
             console.log(json);
             // Here you get your data as JSON, use it to populate your form.

             $("#emailField").val(json.email);
             $("#nameField").val(json.name);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay but for fill my form with json, I must use jQuery ? If yes, Do I must use append function or val() ? I need put an idea for every field of my forrm so, no ?

Comment: Come on, this is all basic stuff, how to use a MySQL request, how to exploit a JSON with jQuery... if you don't know this stuff, google around, there are plenty of tutorials. I have updated my code to show you how to fill some fields. However, since I have no idea of what your MySQL table structure or your HTML code look like, I used `json.email` and `json.name`. Use your actual column names instead.

Comment: So, I can get my data from my DB but I can't add them to the field by using your example. And my console don't show me any errors, just my JSON array.

Comment: Is it important if my variable from DB contain an underscore ? 
Because, my console.log show me my JSON array but when I do : $('#hommes-matin').val(json.UF_LITS_HOMMES_MATIN); it show me nothing and a console.log(json.UF_LITS_HOMMES_MATIN) show me : undefined

Comment: No, it should be okay. This is a valid name, underscores are good. What does the JSON look like? What does the console output?

Comment: "[{"UF_LITS_HOMMES_MATIN":"503","UF_LITS_FEMMES_MATIN":"453","UF_LITS_INDIFF_MATIN":"0","LITS_HOMMES_AM":"0","LITS_FEMMES_AM":"0","LITS_INDIFF_AM":"0","LITS_HOMMES_NUIT":"0","LITS_FEMMES_NUIT":"0","LITS_INDIFF_NUIT":"0"}]" this append on console.log(json)

Comment: Okay so that is an array, that contains one object. So you access it using `json[0]`. Then all your properties are there : `json[0].UF_LITS_HOMMES_MATIN` should give "503".

Comment: Haha, no worries, we finally got you out of the wood. Bon courage ;)